# Terraform arguments not expected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

```
dynamic "condition_threshold" {
        for_each = conditions.value.metric_absence != true ? [conditions.value] : []
        content {
          filter                  = condition_threshold.value.filter
          comparison              = condition_threshold.value.comparison
          threshold_value         = condition_threshold.value.threshold_value
          duration                = condition_threshold.value.duration
          trigger {
            count   = conditions.value.trigger_percentage == null ? conditions.value.trigger_count : null
            percent = conditions.value.trigger_percentage
          }
          aggregations {
            alignment_period     = condition_threshold.value.alignment_period
            per_series_aligner   = condition_threshold.value.per_series_aligner
            cross_series_reducer = condition_threshold.value.cross_series_reducer
            group_by_fields      = condition_threshold.value.group_by_fields
          }
          evaluation_missing_data = "EVALUATION_MISSING_DATA_INACTIVE"
        }
      }
```

I am trying to run this terraform code and i keep getting an error which says An argument named "evaluation_missing_data" is not expected here.
I looked at the documentation and I am doing exactly as it says there and yet it giving out an error.
Any clues on what might the issue be?

I tried giving evaluation_missing_data a constant value instead of dynamic that I did before, yet it did not work.
I tried changing the terraform versions and yet it keeps giving me an error that this argument is not expected here.

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: google      = ">= 3.1"
google-beta = ">= 3.1"
null        = ">= 2.1"
random      = ">= 2.2"

Answer (score 0):

`google = ">= 3.1"` is **very old**. Please use the latest version of a google provider witch is 4.43. Most likely, the `evaluation_missing_data` was added after version 3.1.